# groovy-eclipse-compiler Excludes and Includes not working

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, groovy

I am currently using the groovy-eclipse-compiler and I am trying to include and exclude certain directories under my *src/main/groovy* directory; by default (without filters) the compiler includes everything, but the  filter works when I exclude all groovy files in the source path.

Exclude All Filter works: WORKS
[Build output directory](http://pastebin.com/MrKA4Vi0)

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <!-- <compilerArgument>${COMPILERARGS}</compilerArgument> <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable> -->
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.groovy</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.5-03</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Combination of Include and Excludes: DOES NOT WORK
[Build output directory](http://pastebin.com/bHDemRDP)

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <!-- <compilerArgument>${COMPILERARGS}</compilerArgument> <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable> -->
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>src/main/groovy/controller/**/*.groovy</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/groovy/transformer/listing/**/*.groovy</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/main/groovy/transformer/utils/**/*.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.5-03</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

[Relevant .classpath file data](http://pastebin.com/J25rjxEs#)

[Pom.xml plugins section](http://pastebin.com/eyRB9Hq6)